# Initializing String variable in if-else

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization

I'm trying to write a program here, and in my if-else statement I have `String messageToStudent` initialize if `taskCompleted == 'y' || taskCompleted == 'Y'` , and in my else statement to initialize it for anything else.  however, when I try to compile it says that `messageToStudent` may have not been initialized.  Now, I thought I made it through the code that ONE of the `messageToStudent` strings would initialize, but I guess I was wrong.  Here's what I have so far:

```
if(school == 1) {
    System.out.println(name + ", have you started your engineering project yet?");
    taskCompleted = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (taskCompleted == 'y' || taskCompleted == 'Y')
        messageToStudent = "Good for you! Keep me updated on your progress.";
    System.out.println(messageToStudent);
} else {
    messageToStudent = "That's not good at all. It's nearly November!";
}
System.out.println(messageToStudent);
```

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough. Give it an initial value of `""` or `null` when you declare the variable.

Comment: If school is `1` and taskCompleted is `N`, where is `messageToStudent` initialized?

Comment: you should read up on [NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: From your code, it looks like you're intending to put the `System.out.println(messageToStudent)` inside the `if`-`else` statements, instead of right after them. That, or you're yet to add an `else` statement for when `school == 1`, but taskCompleted is not `y` or `Y` (and initialize `messageToStudent` there as well). In any of those two cases, once your code has been fixed, there wouldn't be a need to initialize `messageToStudent` to `null` or `""` at the beginning, as it will already be initialized when you want to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if `school` was `1` but `taskCompleted` wasn't `'y'` or `'Y'`?  That is the path where `messageToStudent` was not initialized.

Provide a value, even if it's an empty string or `null` at the top, so it is always initialized.